# Is it possible to merge a image1.gift and image2.jpg with .net or javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web, plugins

I want to merge two Images one of them is gif like this:
[image]

and other one is this:

[image]

Now I want put the second image in the gray box of first image. Is it possible to do that with .net or javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question - Yes ;)

OK, now how:

First, you need to find a way to read the gif image you have. 
Example in C# here:
https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2018/march/getting-gif-image-information-using-c/

Then you probably need to take the GIF-Frame(s), and convert it into PNG, copy the the jpeg image at the correct location, then convert the png back to gif, and then create a new gif using
https://github.com/mrousavy/AnimatedGif and set all the frames to the same time as in the original.

For JavaScript, there is [libgif-js](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js) for the browser, and [gif-encoder-2](https://dev.to/benjaminadk/encode-gifs-with-node-4c75) from npm for NodeJS. 
Or you can choose the batch route with ffmpeg.

[Code on github](https://github.com/ststeiger/AnimatedGif)

ImageSharp:

[image: with ImageSharp]

GDI:

[image: with System.Drawing]

ImageSharp - no repeat:

[image: with ImageSharp without repeat]

Comment: Hi
Thank you I'll test it and share the result here

Comment: I did it . Thank you so much

Comment: @shaghayegh sheykholeslami: You can also do it with ImageSharp. Added link to my code on github. That way, it works on Linux, too. My compliments to the friends of autism in Iran ;)